# Read php file located in zip archive

Tags: php, zip, php-ziparchive

I have been trying to read a PHP file inside a ZIP archive. I have coded the following code, which can read text documents and echo without errors, but when I tested it with a PHP file, nothing appear. So what can I do to read the PHP file without extracting?

```
<?php
$zip = zip_open("test.zip");
$filename= "test.php";

if (is_resource($zip))
{
while ($zip_entry = zip_read($zip))
{
    if (zip_entry_open($zip, $zip_entry) && zip_entry_name($zip_entry) == $filename)
    {
        echo "Name: " . zip_entry_name($zip_entry) . "<br />";
        echo "<p>";
        echo "File Contents:<br/>";
        $contents = zip_entry_read($zip_entry);
        echo "$contents<br />";
        zip_entry_close($zip_entry);
    }
}
zip_close($zip);
}
```

Thanks in advance!

Comment: What do you mean you tested it with PHP file?

Comment: I mean I tried the code with a text file with worked and afterwards a PHP file, which could not been read from the zip archive

Comment: Change the double quotes to single quotes and try again `echo "$contents<br />";`

Comment: Just tried that, and it only printed $contents also tried with a txt file.

Answer (score 0):

There aren't a lot of resources out there for using the default zip_read() php function, but this https://github.com/Ne-Lexa/php-zip library makes using zip files in php a breeze, you should check it out.

Comment: Thanks, I will give it a look!

Answer (score 0):

You can use [stream wrappers](http://php.net/manual/en/wrappers.compression.php) to read a file directly from within a zip, in one line, without extracting anything to disk. For example:

```
$str = file_get_contents('zip://test.zip#test.php');
```